# Is it possible to define access code in REDCap?

Tags: redcap

I'm using REDCap in a project, for the very first time.

After importing a "participant list", REDCap automatically generates the "access code" for those users so they can access the questionnaire.

However, after sending those codes to the users a colleague imported again the same participant list into REDCap, which made the list to be the same but the "access codes" changed (are different).

The letters were already sent to the users (with wrong codes, compared to what is now available in REDCap). If users want to answers, they will not have access because of wrong code.

My question:
Is there a way where I can define the "access code", i.e., to change each code to the old one? Or another way to contour this issue?

Comment: There's not a direct way that I'm aware of.  Consider asking your institution's REDCap admin to ask this question on REDCap's private "Community Site".

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what you're asking. You can put the access code on a non-survey form, say the screening log or whatever you're using for your first instrument. Then use the Survey Login feature. That feature you can have any survey participants log in using any field. Then just import the access codes into REDCap and you should be good to go.